# Django: git push heroku master fail

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to push an django web app to heroku for the first time, and  there are some error message as following.

```
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (68/68), done.
Writing objects: 100% (81/81), 105.31 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 81 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing Python-3.5.0
remote:  !     Requested runtime (Python-3.5.0) is not available for this     stack
(cedar-14).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info:     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pytho
n-support
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to polar-lake-12528.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/polar-lake-12528.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/polar-lake-12528.git'
```

My runtime.txt looks like:

```
python-3.5.1
```

I have already changed to lowercase and update the version of python to 3.5.1, but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.5.0 is not supported. You can change it to `python-3.5.1`.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#supported-python-runtimes for supported runtimes.

Comment: I have already update the version of python , but heroku still detects python 3.5.0. It doesn't work after changing runtime.txt to python-3.5.1.